# What is "adb.bash" used for?

Tags: android, shell

in the script ./build/envsetup.sh
in the function addcompletions() it finally run the command . /sdk/bash_completion/adb.bash
What is this command here for?
And what is the script "adb.bash" used for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file sets up integration between the bash shell and adb.  Specifically, it sets up command line completion, so you can type "adb " and press tab, and get a list of adb commands you can use.  Briefly skimming it, it seems like it might also support remote file listing by pressing tab twice in contexts where that is appropriate (e.g. after 'adb pull').